# What is cause of ORA-38104 error on SQL merge?

Tags: oracle, merge, ora-38104

I have a code like this

```
MERGE INTO target_table tgt
USING source_table src
on(tgt.c1=src.c1)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET tgt.c1=src.c2
```

I get `ORA-38104: Columns referenced in the ON clause cannot be updated`. I understand the reason for this error. But how can we rewrite this code? Is there any possibilities without using cursor?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about this, the outer join means the `rid` will be null and thus fail, and so flow into the `WHEN NOT MATCHED` part of the statement if you have one

```
MERGE INTO target_table tgt
USING ( SELECT t2.ROWID AS rid
            ,  s2.c2
        FROM   target_table t2
             , source_table s2
        WHERE t2.c1 (+) = s2.c1
      ) src
ON (tgt.rowid = src.rid)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET tgt.c1=src.c2
```

Comment: I'm getting this error `ORA-01445-cannot select ROWID from a join view without a key-preserved table Cause: A SELECT statement attempted to select ROWIDs from a view derived from a join operation. Because the rows selected in the view do not correspond to underlying physical records, no ROWIDs can be returned. ` if i use this query

Comment: You must be doing something slightly different. Are you sure you have `t2.ROWID AS something`? It would NOT be valid to use `src.ROWID` which is why I aliased it `AS rid`

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I missed to rename `t2.ROWID` as `rid`. Its working fine after i add the alias name. Thank you Sodved :)

Comment: This was great but , It was working for me on updates but did not insert any rows when i try with 'when not matched then ' statement. Please help me out. also i tried with insert several columns by using src.name likewise for the columns. still it says 0 rows merged even it was not matched. Would be a great help if i can get some help in here.

Answer (score 0):

[You can exploit some workarounds for ORA-38104](https://blog.jooq.org/2019/01/02/how-to-work-around-ora-38104-columns-referenced-in-the-on-clause-cannot-be-updated/), which seem to work up until Oracle 18c, including this one, where you'd wrap your columns in a row value expression that contains an additional dummy expression:

```
MERGE INTO target_table tgt
USING source_table src
ON ((tgt.c1, 'dummy') = ((src.c1, 'dummy')))
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET tgt.c1=src.c2
```