# MERGE using a rowtype variable in PL/SQL on Oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql, sql-merge

With a variable `bar` of the type `foo%ROWTYPE` I can do both `INSERT` and `UPDATE` in PL/SQL:

```
INSERT INTO foo VALUES bar;
```

```
UPDATE foo SET ROW = bar WHERE id = bar.id;
```

But how do I do a `MERGE`? The following approach generates the error message below:

```
MERGE INTO foo USING bar ON foo.id = bar.id
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET ROW = bar
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT VALUES bar;
```

> PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Comment: believe this has been answered on the oracle  forums here  https://community.oracle.com/thread/621511?start=0&tstart=0 look at Solomon's answer.  There is also a FORALL Merge that might work for you.  http://www.morganslibrary.org/reference/plsql/array_processing.html

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Solomons answer is enumerating all the fields of the rowtype, which sort of takes away the whole point of using a rowtype. I'm not sure I understand how a `FORALL MERGE` would help here. The solution from MichaelS looks promising, though.

Comment: Nope, cant get MichaelS answer to work either. I just get `ORA-38104: Columns referenced in the ON Clause cannot be updated: foo.id`

Comment: It might help if you give as a more lifelike example. You're inserting/updating  "foo". But what is "bar" ? a table with the same structure? Or just a rowtype you previously defined?

Comment: @NonPlusUltra As the question says, `bar` is a variable of the type `foo%ROWTYPE`. `foo` is a table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer MichaelS gives in the thread mentioned above should work fine. The error message you're receiving (ORA-38104: Columns referenced in the ON Clause cannot be updated: foo.id) suggests you're trying to do something similar to the following:

```
merge into foo
  using (select null from dual)
  on (foo.id = bar.id)
  when matched then update set foo.id = bar.id, foo.another_field = bar.another_field
  when not matched then insert VALUES bar;
```

As the error states, columns referenced in the "ON" clause cannot be updated. As such, the following would work fine:

```
merge into foo
  using (select null from dual)
  on (foo.id = bar.id)
  when matched then update set foo.another_field = bar.another_field
  when not matched then insert VALUES bar;
```

If you really need to update foo.id, there is a possible solution here: [How to avoid ORA-3814 error on merge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7886905/how-to-avoid-ora-3814-error-on-merge)

**Edit**

A possible alternative would be to do the following:

```
update foo set row = bar where foo.id = bar.id;

if sql%rowcount = 0 then
  insert into foo values bar;
end if;
```

This should essentially equate to doing the same thing as the merge statement.

Comment: Unless you really need to use a merge statement for some reason, I have added a possible alternative solution for you. As stated by Solomon Yakobson (https://community.oracle.com/thread/621511?start=0&tstart=0)  you cannot use a rowtype in the when matched clause of a merge statement

Comment: in this case - generally what is faster  
option 1 - merge  or the option 2  -  update and then insert using IF

Comment: Personally not sure, but according to the answer over here, the merge: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16028/oracles-merge-v-select-update-insert